# Is it possible to call one event of Kendo UI inside another event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Can someone answer how to call `databound`-event inside `save` event in Kendo UI?

The requirement is to access the KendoGrid data dynamically (as and when it changes). (I tried using the change function, but it is not firing.)

So I think, my requirement would be possible by calling the databound event inside the save  function, so that I get the latest value as well as and when it changes.

**P.S**:- I cant use `this.refresh();` function inside the save function because, there's another requirement for me to add a new row when pressing enter key.

Comment: show your full kendo.grid code, or at least save event

Comment: @GeneR Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/aravind_93/Lw6awf6g/

Comment: @GeneR Is there anything which you could suggest for doing this?

Comment: i would suggest set model in save event:`e.model.set('someFieldName', e.values[someFieldName])`